# Возможен ли импорт файла который по пути ниже

Tags: python, импорт, python-import

Название вопроса немного непонятно, вообщем есть вот такая структура

```
direktoria:
  | foo.py
  | direktoria2:
    | bar.py
```

Мне нужно в файле `bar.py` импортировать файл `foo.py`
Если бы они были на одном уровне я бы просто сделал `import foo.py`
Но в этом случае не работает даже например `__import__("..\\foo")`

Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Аж два ответа:-) Но вариант @Namerek мне больше нравится:-) Он еще и про путь не забыл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В случае если `PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/direktoria`.

```py
from direktoria import foo
```

Answer (score 2):

1. должно работать:

   ```
    import direktoria.foo
   ```
2. должно быть возможно с .pth файлами